# C# WPF - How to change which window opens first

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

This is a very, very simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer. I have a WPF application that I've made a bunch of windows for. I've decided now that I want a different window to be the first one to open when the application is started. The default first window is MainWindow, how do I change it so another window opens first?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Open your App.xaml file and update the StartupUri:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfHacking.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"> <!-- This is the line you want to update -->
</Application>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this from the code behind by overriding the 'OnStartup' method in App.xaml.cs as below.

***Do take note to remove the StartupUri="Test.xaml" from the App.xaml***

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            Test window = new Test();
            window.Show();
        }
```